# How can I download an old version of the Android support library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I'm targeting Android 19 (because that's what my phone is running). I want to add a notification with buttons; it seems the right approach is to use appcompat-v7.app.NotificationCompat.

However, when I add appcompat-v7 from the Android Support repository revision 22.2 (via a build.gradle dependency), it includes a file app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml that doesn't compile because it assumes the target is 21+.

I tried deleting that file, but it gets regenerated.

There doesn't seem to be a way to exclude a file from the build.

So, I need to get an older version of the support library or repository, that doesn't include 21 stuff.

I guess I could import all the sources directly (and leave out the v21 stuff), rather than thru the dependency? I'm not clear where to start with that.
I can use the SDK manager to get older versions of the SDK, but it only offers the latest version of the support library.

Comment: huh? always target newest stable API with newest support library with newest build tools ... you should get lint's waringing if you are using stuff from API > minSdk ... if you don't have any, then it should run on all device with API lvl >= minSdk without problems

Comment: add your gradle config

Comment: use `targetSdkVersion` and `compiledSdkVersion` = 21 to resolve your issue

Comment: I was not used to relying on Lint, but I've started using it more, so I tried bumping targetSdkVersion. However, that still gives the same error.

Comment: Adding "compileSdkVersion" (without the 'd') fixed it. I'm still wary of compiling against a new SDK version; everytime I've changed to a new version, something breaks. But this time it seems nothing did.

Comment: "I'm still wary of compiling against a new SDK version; everytime I've changed to a new version, something breaks" -- all this does is change the local JAR you compile against, for resolving classes, methods, fields, etc. The only actual changes in your resulting APK would be from static fields whose values change, and that does not happen very often (IOW, I cannot name any case where it ever has). I have yet to hear of any confirmed case of "something breaks" *solely* from changing `compileSdkVersion`. If you have a concrete example, I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: @Selvin This is a very very bad advice. It results in broken applications to say the least. Mostly it is even impossible to compile. Don't believe everything you read in docs, Docs are just marketing material.

Comment: It is only very bad advice if you don't know how to write compatible apps. For the rest of the android's developers  is a good advice...  Of course you have to know what new api changed... Also there is no possibility to compile app which using newest compat library without changing compileSdk to the same as compat library is using...

Comment: @Selvin This is very naive. Once you have stable app it is very risky to advance especially in regard to build tools. Well I believe things might go through in a trivial hello world style app, but as soon as you have something more complex, project with multiple libraries, complex styles and themes, simple update of build tools might turn into a horror. But suit your self...

Answer (score 2):

In your gradle build file change the dependency to be the 19 version (the version of the library should match the sdk you are compiling with):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
...
}
```

Edit:  If v19 of the support lib doesn't have NotificationCompat, then you can't use that unless you compile against a later SDK.  You can't include a support library with a higher version than your compiled SDK - that's the issue you are running into.

In this case change:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    ...
}
```

and leave the dependency set to the 22 version of the appcompat support lib

Comment: there is a one small problem ... v19.0.+/19.1.+ doesn't contains app.NotificationCompat class

Comment: @Selvin Ahh if that's the case, then the OP can't use NotificationCompat if targeting SDK 19 - he would have to target a later SDK where the corresponding lib supports NotificationCompat.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Right. The reason I'm using the support library is because I want access to a feature that's introduced in API 21, so of course I need to target that level.

Comment: Updated to reflect it's the compileSdkVersion that matters - not the target (although if you changed the target version you would have to bump the compile version by definition).

Answer (score 2):

to directly answer your question it's all that one line on gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

That last part is the version you're getting. `22.2.0` on the example above.

and on this link you can check the revisions numbers:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions

But you have a fundamentally wrong approach to your issue. You don't have to target the API for the device you have with you. You can easily and safely target the latest API, use the latest `AppCompat` features and bug fixes.

Lint will give you a warning every time you try to use a feature that is not from your `minimumApi`, regardless of the `targetAPI`

Comment: Wrong. You have to target coorrect API if you want your app to remain in working condition.

Comment: @Laser if you read all his comments, you'll see that he's just a bad developer without real understand of what's going on behind the scenes and is trolling SO spreading FUD. Yes there's differences on API but my answer is to simply compile to the latest API, not to code only against it.